# Plot[Evaluate[compiled functions... causes problems

Tags: plotting, compile, hold

I'm sure there is an easy solution to this, but I have beaten my head against a wall for a couple of days, so I hope someone can help.

I have compiled functions. For a minimal example let's take:

```
fn1 = Compile[{{t, _Real}, {x, _Real}}, Sin[t x]];
fn2 = Compile[{{t, _Real}, {x, _Real}}, Cos[t x]];
```

The list of functions I want to plot is dynamic, so I cannot explicitly list them. We can model this using `Through`, though there are many ways to do this:

```
Plot[Through[{fn1, fn2}[3, x]], {x, 0, 10}]
```

But this plots both curves with the same color because with the `Hold` attribute of Plot, the head `Through` evaluates as a single item. The standard way to fix this problem is to use `Evaluate`:

```
Plot[Evaluate@Through[{fn1, fn2}[3, x]], {x, 0, 10}]
```

But this gives errors:

> CompiledFunction: Argument x at position 2 should be a machine-size real number.

Clearly this is because MMA is trying to `Evaluate` the x before a value has been assigned to it by Plot. How can we avoid this problem (other than just suppressing the warning messages)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using [`Inactive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive)/[`Activate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Activate), e.g.:

```
With[{in = {fn1, fn2} /. CompiledFunction -> Inactive[CompiledFunction]},
    Activate @ Inactive[Plot][Through[in[3, x]], {x, 0, 10}]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! This opens up a whole new world for me!

Answer (score 0):

And the [power of the post](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Power%20of%20the%20Post).

```
Plot[Evaluate@(Hold[#[3, x]] & /@ {fn1, fn2}), {x, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: This relies on the undocumented feature that Hold wrappers get automatically stripped by Plot. There is no guarantee that this feature will not be removed in the future.